# catalogsearch_fulltext count after finished reindexing

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalogsearch, indexer

I know I can watch the progress of the indexer if I look at the database table `catalogsearch_fulltext`.

What will be the count of rows after the reindexing is finished?

I guess it is related to product count, searchable attributes and store view? I have 76051 products, 16 searchable attributes, 2 stores.

Comment: The row count might not properly reflect the current progress, as indexing is done in transactions and/or with large bulk-inserts.

Comment: I just like to have an estimation if there will be 100'000 or a million rows at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the size of `catalogsearch_fulltext` is **products * stores**

With my 76051 products and 2 store views it finished at `152,102`.